# Calling an API in PHP without cURL

Tags: php, rest, api, http

After writing the cURL script to to get what I wanted - I found out that the web server doesn't support cURL and only supports pure PHP. How would I go about doing this in pure PHP?

```
    <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xx.xxxx.xxx/xxx/blog/micro");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Header1: Header1Input',
    'Header1: Header2Input',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
 $json = $server_output;
 $data = json_decode($json);


print  $data[1]->Headline;?>
```

Is what has managed to work for me.

I have tried this approach for pure PHP:

```
    <?php

// Create a stream
$opts = [
    "http" => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "header" => "Header1: Header1Input" .
            "Header2: Header2Input"
            ]
        ];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('https://xx.xxxx.xxx/xxx/blog/micro', false, $context);

$file = json_decode($file);


print  $file[1]->Headline;?>
?>
```

However I get this error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see the problem in the `header` after each line you have to add `\r\n` (CR LF).

This is defined [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2).

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all
>   protocol elements except the entity-body.

Answer (score 2):

Using a **cURL emulator class**, such as https://github.com/vavrecan/curl-emulator, you also get support for CURLOPT options.